# How to default to CLoader in PyYaml.load

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Is there any way to have the default loader for PyYaml be CLoader. So instead of having to do

```
yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.CLoader)
```

It would just default to CLoader, so I could do:

```
yaml.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools

myload=functools.partial(yaml.load,Loader=yaml.CLoader)
myload(f)
```